# Compare dates between seasons into following year

Tags: php, date, date-range

I have 3 seasons (this is how the client charges), 
season 1 starts 1st April & ends 31st July (2021-04-01 to 2021-07-31)
season 2 starts 1st August & ends 30th November (2021-08-01 to 2021-11-30)
season 3 starts 1st December & ends 31st March (2021-12-01 to 2022-03-31
Season 3 spans from one year into the next year(Dec to Mar)

The dates are from DB in this format **2021-11-03**. I replace the seasons year with the booking_start & booking_end year with $BSyear & $BEyear.

**Below I have code for the seasons plus one year for other calculations as I only need to go one year into the future.**

My issue is I can get season 1 & season 2 to work but I'm having an issue with season 3. I think it may be because it crosses from one year to the next but I can't get my head around what's causing the issue.

Are my >= calculations done correctly or are they conflicting with each other? Season 3 calculation is at the very bottom.

```
    $BS ="2021-06-02";//booking start date will become a POSTED FORM VARIABLE HERE
    list($BSyear, $BSmonth, $BSday) = explode("-", $BS);
    $booking_start = $BSyear.'-'.$BSmonth.'-'.$BSday;
    $booking_start = strtotime($booking_start);

    
        //BOOKING END
    $BE ="2021-06-04";//booking end date will become a POSTED FORM VARIABLE HERE
    list($BEyear, $BEmonth, $BEday) = explode("-", $BE);
    $booking_end = $BEyear.'-'.$BEmonth.'-'.$BEday;
    $booking_end = strtotime($booking_end);
    
    
    //...........START: Row 1 Season 1 Dates...........\\
    
    $id = 1;
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM season_switch WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();


    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {    


    //output data of row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        
        $SS1 .= $row["start_date"];//SS1 stands for season 1 start
        $SE1 .= $row["end_date"];//SE1 stands for season 1 end
        
        $SS1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($SS1));
        $SE1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($SE1));
        
        //Season start
    list($SS1year, $SS1month, $SS1day) = explode("-", $SS1);
    $season_start = $BSyear.'-'.$SS1month.'-'.$SS1day;//Season 1 start year gets booking end year value here with $BSyear
    $season_start = strtotime($season_start);
    
    
        //Season end
    list($SE1year, $SE1month, $SE1day) = explode("-", $SE1);
    $season_end = $BEyear.'-'.$SE1month.'-'.$SE1day;//Season 1 end year gets booking end year value here with $BEyear
    $season_end = strtotime($season_end);
    
    }
    }
    else{
    echo "0 results available for season 1".'<BR>';
    }
    //...........END: Row 1 Season 1 Dates...........\\
        
    //...........START: Row 2 Season 2 Dates...........\\
    
    $id = 2;
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM season_switch WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {    


    //output data of row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        
        $SS2 .= $row["start_date"];//SS2 stands for season 2 start
        $SE2 .= $row["end_date"];//SE2 stands for season 2 end
        
        $SS2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($SS2));
        $SE2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($SE2));
        
        //Season 2 start
    list($SS2year, $SS2month, $SS2day) = explode("-", $SS2);
    $season2_start = $BSyear.'-'.$SS2month.'-'.$SS2day;//Season 2 start year gets booking end year value here with $BSyear
    $season2_start = strtotime($season2_start);
    
        //Season 2 end
    list($SE2year, $SE2month, $SE2day) = explode("-", $SE2);
    $season2_end = $BEyear.'-'.$SE2month.'-'.$SE2day;//Season 2 end year gets booking end year value here with $BEyear
    $season2_end = strtotime($season2_end);
    
    }
    }
    else{
    echo "0 results available for season 2".'<BR>';
    }
    //...........END: Row 2 Season 2 Dates...........\\
    
    //...........START: Row 3 Season 3 Dates...........\\

    
    $id = 3;
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM season_switch WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();


    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {    


    //output data of row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        
        $SS3 .= $row["start_date"];//SS3 stands for season 3 start
        $SE3 .= $row["end_date"];//SE3 stands for season 3 end
        
        $SS3 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($SS3));
        $SE3 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($SE3));
        
        
        //Season 3 start    
    list($SS3year, $SS3month, $SS3day) = explode("-", $SS3);
    $season3_start = $BSyear.'-'.$SS3month.'-'.$SS3day;//Season 3 start year gets booking end year value here with $BSyear
    $season3_start = strtotime($season3_start);
    
        //Season 3 end
    list($SE3year, $SE3month, $SE3day) = explode("-", $SE3);
    $season3_end = $BEyear.'-'.$SE3month.'-'.$SE3day;//Season 3 end year gets booking end year value here with $BEyear
    $season3_end = strtotime($season3_end);
    
    }
    }
    else{
    echo "0 results available for season 3".'<BR>';
    }
    //...........END: Row 3 Season 3 Dates...........\\

    
    //For when season 1 goes into next year
    $season_start_plus_1_year = strtotime('+ 1 year', $season_start);
    $season_end_plus_1_year = strtotime('+ 1 year', $season_end);
    
    //-------------------
    
    //For when season 2 goes into next year
    $season2_start_plus_1_year = strtotime('+ 1 year', $season2_start);
    $season2_end_plus_1_year = strtotime('+ 1 year', $season2_end);
    
    //-------------------

    
    //For when season 3 goes into next year
    $season3_start_plus_1_year = strtotime('+ 1 year', $season3_start);
    $season3_end_plus_1_year = strtotime('+ 1 year', $season3_end);
    //-------------------



//-------------START: COMPLEATLY IN SEASON 1 or 2 or 3 ---------------// 

        //compleatly season 1
        if($booking_start >= $season_start and $booking_start <= $season_end and $booking_end > $season_start and $booking_end <= $season_end) {
            
            $low_mid_peak_switch = 1;
            $datediff = $booking_end - $booking_start;
            echo '<span style="color:red;">'.'Booking is compleatly in SEASON 1'.'</span>';
            echo '<BR>';
            echo $datediff ='<span style="color:limegreen;">'.round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24)).' days @ Season 1 price $'.'</span>';
            echo '<BR>';
            exit;
        
    }
    
    
        //compleatly season 2   
        if($booking_start >= $season2_start and $booking_start <= $season2_end and $booking_end > $season2_start and $booking_end <= $season2_end) {
            
            $low_mid_peak_switch = 2;
            echo '<span style="color:red;">'.'Booking is compleatly in SEASON 2'.'</span>';
            echo '<BR>';
            $datediff = $booking_end - $booking_start;
            echo '<span style="color:OliveDrab;">'.round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24)).' days @ Season 2 price $'.'</span>';
            echo '<BR>';
            exit;
        
    }
    
        //compleatly season 3
        if($booking_start >= $season3_start && $booking_end <= $season3_end) {
            
            $low_mid_peak_switch = 3;
            echo '<span style="color:red;">'.'Booking is compleatly in SEASON 3'.'</span>';
            echo '<BR>';
            $datediff = $booking_end - $booking_start;
            echo '<span style="color:LightSeaGreen;">'.round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24)).' days @ Season 3 price $'.'</span>';
            echo '<BR>';
            exit;
    }
    
//-------------END: COMPLEATLY IN SEASON 1 or 2 or 3 ---------------//
```

Comment: If you could hold tight, for 3 more hours. Ill get off work and go home, help you with a solid and properly working solution.(I saw this question today).

Comment: Hi, you can simply split the season that crosses newyear, set all year numbers to 2000, and check if the date falls within one of both ranges. You can find an example implementation [here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.SeasonChecker/blob/master/MintPlayer.SeasonChecker/SeasonChecker.cs#L87-L124).